# MSBuild - Run tests only on Release build

Tags: msbuild, automated-tests

Our MSBuild definitions build both Debug and Release build configurations. (This is due to the deployment system we use and can't be changed.) The problem is that since we run automated tests, they are run twice, once on each build. Is there any way for me to configure tests to be run only on release build?

We're using VS2010/TFS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a little tweak to Nick's answer did the trick.

```
..\Release\**\MyApp*Tests.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

In the TFS build definition, under the **Process** tab, under Automated Tests -> Test Sources -> Test Sources Spec, can you modify the path spec to include the name of the releases folder so that the test binaries from the releases folder only are tested?

Change the spec from:

```
**\MyApp*Tests.dll
```

To read:

```
**\Release\**\MyApp*Tests.dll
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. Our original spec was `**\*test*.dll`. I tried `**\Release\**\*test*dll` and `**\Release\*test*.dll`.